# What is ORC double datatype equivalent in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have ORC files that have columns with `double` datatype in the file, these columns are queryable in AWS Athena as numeric(18,0). This is the best I could find on the byte length of the destination Redshift datatype: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html. I tried float4 and float8 but those did not work.

```
ERROR: Spectrum Scan Error Detail: 
----------------------------------------------- 
error: Spectrum Scan Error code: 15007 context: 
In file https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/....zlib.orc declared column type DECIMAL for column <test_column> incompatible with 
ORC file column type double query: 40933 location: dory_util.cpp:1167 process: worker_thread [pid=1299] 
----------------------------------------------- 
[ErrorId: 1-6233d72e-4401a9ae4a9f92432ebc9fcf]
```

Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE "schema"."table" (
    col1 float,
    col2 decimal(18,0) encode az64, # FAILS source ORC - double
    col3 float4, # FAILS source ORC - double
    # col4 numeric(18,0) encode az64, # AWS Glue representation source ORC - double
    col5 character varying(256) encode lzo
);
```

Code that fails:

```
COPY "schema"."table"
FROM 's3://.../database/table/' IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/TestIAM'
FORMAT AS ORC
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using decimal data type, Use double precision as it is standard data type of Redshift for decimal or float values

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).